# Autorunning program on a USB drive

Tags: usb, windows-10

Is there a way to automatically run a program (e.g. Python or C++) on a USB drive and bypass the popup window in Windows 10 (showing the different choices you have for the drive)?

I have seen that someone converted a USB drive to U3-USB and were running it as a CD instead. Not sure if this works in Windows 10 though.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, YES!

You can spoof USB HID, and then from there you can do anything. It isn't as simple as autorun though. I recommend using the digispark microcontroller (ATTiny) <- I used it, I can endorse it!

EDIT: If you need any help, say so, I can guide you

Edit no 2. Things like USBKill are a good defense against this kinda stuff

Comment: consider an attack where a USB identifies itself as a hub, mounts a keyboard and mouse and also mounts a disk (instead of using the UI to create a program file), and then loads malware and executes it. It's also possible to load a small program like a shell script execute cURL'd code (or whatever NT equivalent)

Answer (score 1):

As I know the answare is **NO**!

It's just about hardware, not a software trick. The hardware structure of U3 devices make them auto-runnable as a cd. so you can buy a U3-USB :)